# Weird numpy matrix values

Tags: numpy, matrix

When i want to calculate the determinant of matrix using <<np.linalg.det(mat1)>> or calculate the inverse it gives weird value output . For example it gives 1.11022302e-16 instead of 0.

I tried to round the number for determinant but i couldn't do the same for matrix elements.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the computation is a not fix numbers so multiplication or division very close to zero but not equals.

You can define a delta that can determine if its close enough, and then compute the the absolute distance between the result and the expected value.

Maybe like this:

```
res = np.linalg.det(mat)

delta = 0.0001

if abs(math.floor(res)-res)<delta:
    return math.floor(res)

if abs(math.ceil(res)-res)<delta:
    return math.ceil(res)

return res
```